# How can ldapsearch look for a specific user with a specific group?

Tags: ldap

I'm working on some ldap authentication, and one of the things I need to do is require users be part of a specific group. To best replicate the functionality I can use this query

```
ldapsearch -x -H "ldap://ldap.server.edu:389" -P 3 -LLL -b "dc=something,dc=something" "(&(|(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(objectclass=person)(objectclass=umichPerson))(uid=theuid)(memberOf=cn=groupname,ou=User Groups,ou=Groupsdc=something,dc=something))"
```

I removed some of the identifying parts. What's throwing me off is, I'm new to using LDAP, but from searching around, the "memberof" portion sounds like it's supposed to work.

If I ran this query, I'm able to pull up the group without any issues

```
ldapsearch -x -H "ldap://ldap.server.edu:389" -P 3 -LLL -b "cn=groupname,ou=User Groups,ou=Groupsdc=something,dc=something"
```

So back to the original problem, the code seems to search the base DN, then use the filter. The bind happens with the user credentials, so I know they're a user of the organization, but I can't get the filter right to confirm they're a user who should be allowed access. If member/memberof/ismemberof doesn't work, are there other ways to use this filter? Or is there another filter anyone can suggest that might get the same results?

I've reached out to my IT group, but it's been a week without any response, so I'm thinking I'll be on my own for this one.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm new to using LDAP, but from searching around, the "memberof" portion sounds like it's supposed to work.

Yes, but that does require that:

- the LDAP directory actually populates the `memberOf` attribute.
  There is a certain additional overhead and complexity for the LDAP server to ensure that a change in the members of a group in one place also triggers reciprocal updates elsewhere in the `memberOf` attributes of the members that were added/removed.
  In for example OpenLDAP that requires activating a separate overlay (See [§12.8. Reverse Group Membership Maintenance](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Reverse%20Group%20Membership%20Maintenance) of the manual).

Deconstructing your LDAP filter:

```
"(
   &                                 # Logical AND : match all requirements
     (                               # Requirement 1 
       |                             # Logical OR match 1 or more 
         (objectclass=inetOrgPerson)
         (objectclass=person)
         (objectclass=umichPerson)
     )
     (                               # Requirement 2 
        uid=theuid
     )
     (                               # Requirement 3 
        memberOf=cn=groupname,ou=User Groups,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=edu
     )
 )"
```

I would start with a more limited filter, only testing requirement 2, to see if:

1. you actually find a user
2. that user has `memberOf` attributes

i.e. do a simple search like

```
ldapsearch -x -H "ldap://ldap.example.edu:389" -P 3 -LLL -b "dc=example,dc=edu" "(uid=theuid)"  memberOf
```

and confirm it returns something useful like:

```
dn: uid=theuid,ou=People,dc=example,dc=edu
memberOf: cn=groupname,ou=User Groups,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=edu
```

And then test by adding further conditions and requirements in your filter.

Your "requirement 1" `(|(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(objectclass=person)(objectclass=umichPerson))`  appears a test to ensure that only people are allowed to authenticate. Depending on your search base and LDAP directory layout that may or not be a necessary step to for example prevent service accounts from authenticating.

---

If the `memberOf` attribute is not available, you can use a different approach:

- Check if the user is in the  `member` or `uniqueMember` attributes of the group with a filter like:

  ```
     (&(objectclass=groupOfNames)(member=uid=theuid,ou=People,dc=example,dc=edu))
  ```

Note that this won't work when nested groups are used for example.

```
 ldapsearch -x -H "ldap://ldap.example.edu:389" -P 3 -LLL -b "cn=groupname,ou=User Groups,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=edu" "(&(objectclass=groupOfNames)(member=uid=theuid,ou=People,dc=example,dc=edu))"
```

Comment: Memberof does not seem to work. Your second solution does give results, however, I'm returning the group instead of the member.

Comment: You don't need the member itself, only the positive result that the person is in that group, right?